# Spark CSV file writing error when date in name - InvalidClassException: org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateParser

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-dataset

We have following spark code to write CSV file with DATE in it's name.

outputfile name e.g. Example-FIle-**2020-11-24**

For date conversion - we are using JAVA `SimpleDateFormat`

```
DateFormat dfOut = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
outputPath = "ABC" + dfout.format(date);
```

```
Dataset.coalesce(1)
                .write()
                .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZ")
                .option("header", "true")
                .option("nullValue", null)
                .option("emptyValue", null)
                .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
                .csv(outputPath);
```

Spark application fails randomly on cluster.
Spark tries to execute application on the same executor multiple times. After that we get blacklist* node related error.

ERROR -

```
20/11/24 05:21:55 ERROR datasources.FileFormatWriter: Aborting job b1252410-7869-48ad-8d69-10dd5fa54c12.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
Aborting TaskSet 1.0 because task 0 (partition 0)
cannot run anywhere due to node and executor blacklist.
Most recent failure:
Lost task 0.1 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, ap-cdpdn8p.oneadr.net, executor 4): java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateParser; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3, local class serialVersionUID = 2
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:699)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1885)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1363)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:413)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Blacklisting behavior can be configured via spark.blacklist.*.
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1890)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:929)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2111)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2060)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2049)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:740)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2081)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
        at com.nordea.nrc.idv.IDVIntentsExportingEngine.run(IDVIntentsExportingEngine.java:59)
        at com.nordea.nrc.idv.IDVIntentsExportingMain.main(IDVIntentsExportingMain.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:667)
20/11/24 05:21:55 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Driver requested a total number of 0 executor(s).
20/11/24 05:21:55 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
```

Answer (score 0):

In trying to save your dataframe to CSV, you are using the `coalesce(1)` function in your DataFrameWriter. Coalesce function decreases the number of partitions of the DataFrame to the number passed to it, 1 in your case. This causes all the data to move to One executor while saving, causing the application to crash. Try to save the application by removing the Coalesce function. try the code below.

```
            Dataset
            .write
            .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZ")
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("nullValue", null)
            .option("emptyValue", null)
            .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
            .csv(outputPath);
```